# How can I improve efficiency in this lookup program?

Tags: performance, matlab

I have two large data sets--search is 340,000 x 1 and field is 348,000 x 2. My goal is to use the elements in search, find its position in field(:,1) and then use the corresponding values in field(:,2) to create a new cell array called result.

I ran out of memory using cellfun directly, so I had to split the data sets into subsets and then compile the results.

I built the following program to do so, but it takes a surprisingly long time: 2 hours and 40 minutes!

My question is this, how can I perform this task more efficiently? Do I need to modify my existing code or do I need to take a whole different approach at solving the problem?

```
function result = bigdatacmp(search,field)

%BIGDATACMP(SEARCH,FIELD) takes strcmp jobs that require excessive amounts
%   memory and splits them up into manageable subsets. The results of the
%   subsets are then compiled to represent the original set.


tic

subsets = floor(size(search,1)/1000);       %Divides search into subsets
difference = size(search,1) - 1000*subsets; %# of elements in last subset

result = cell(0);                           %Establish empty variables

%Loops through all subsets. Finds location of matches in the first column
%of field. Compiles subset locations. Compiles results from second column
%of field.
for i = 1:subsets

    searchvalues = search(1000*i-999:1000*i);

    Zlogic = cellfun(@(x)(strcmp(x,field(:,1))),...
        search(1000*i-999:1000*i),'UniformOutput',false);

    result(1000*i-999:1000*i) = cellfun(@(x)(field(x,2)),...
        Zlogic,'UniformOutput',false);
end

%Performs same calculations as in loop, but for the final subset.
Zlogic = cellfun(@(x)(strcmp(x,field(:,1))),search(size(search,1)-...
    difference+1:size(search,1)),'UniformOutput',false);

result(end+1:end+difference) = cellfun(@(x)(field(x,2)),Zlogic,...
    'UniformOutput',false);

result = result';

toc
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

348k isn't all that large. Consider building a `containers.Map` object mapping things from the first column of `field` to the corresponding entries in the second column. Then you won't need to do what amounts to an exhaustive search of `field` for every entry in `search`.

[EDITED to add:] If 348k is the total number of entries, I don't think there should be any need to split things up further.

Comment: Thank you for sharing `containers.Map` with me. It sounds like it will solve my currently problem perfectly and be very useful in the future as well. I am currently exploring a solution, but I've run into an error: `Error using containers.Map/values
The specified key is not present in this container.` Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: You probably want the `isKey` method.

Comment: Thanks, Gareth. That is exactly what I was looking for.